# computing Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{x^2+a^2},\, a > 0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

after a decomposition of the fraction we get : $$\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac 1 {x^2+a^2} \right\} = \frac{i}{2a} [\Xi_{➷ }(\xi) -\Xi^{➹}(\xi)]$$

where : 
$$\Xi^{➹}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-i\xi x}}{x -ia}\,dx $$

$$\Xi_{➷ }(\xi)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-i\xi x}}{x +ia}\,dx $$

[image]

let $\Gamma_R = \gamma_R \cup[-R,R]$

then $$\lim_{R \to +\infty} \oint_{\Gamma_R} \frac{e^{-i \xi z}}{z-ia}\,dz = \Xi^{➹}(\xi)+  \lim_{R \to +\infty} \oint_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{-i \xi z}}{z-ia} \,dz$$

on the one hand we have : $$\lim_{R \to +\infty} \oint_{\Gamma_R } \frac{e^{-i \xi z}}{z-ia}\,dz = 2\pi i \star \operatorname*{\textbf{Res}}_{ia} = 2\pi ie^{a \xi }$$

on $\gamma_R$ we have $z = Re^{i\theta},\, \theta \in [0,\pi]$

using Jensen's inequality
$$\left| \oint_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{-i \xi z}}{z-ia}\,dz\right| \leq \oint_{\gamma_R } \frac{|e^{-i \xi z}|}{|z-ia|}\,dz = \frac{1}{R}\oint_{\gamma_R } \frac{dz}{\sqrt{(\cos^2 \theta + (\sin \theta - a)^2}} \to 0 \text{ as } R \to \infty \text{, right ?}$$

so $$\Xi^{➹}(\xi) = 2\pi ie^{a \xi }$$

for the other one I just need to swap the contour upside down.

but I'm fairly certain I'm wrong when I concluded that the integral tends to $0$ because even though the $R$ was out it still somehow depended on it.

my main goal is to find the above Fourier transform, is there another way to do it ? if not how do you deal with $\lim_{R \to +\infty} \oint_{\gamma_R } \frac{e^{-i \xi z}}{z-ia}\,dz$

Edit : I just realized that : $$ \frac{1}{R}\oint_{\gamma_R } \frac{dz}{\sqrt{(\cos^2 \theta + (\sin \theta - a)^2}} =  \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta}{\sqrt{(\cos^2 \theta + (\sin \theta - a)^2}}$$

so my conclusion is wrong.

Comment: I did some minor copy-editing including the use of \left and \right in two places, making the delimiters grow to the sizes of what they enclose, but also I found this:
$$
2\pi i \star \textbf{Res}_{ia} = 2\pi ie^{a \xi }
$$
and I changed it to this:
$$
2\pi i \star \operatorname*{\textbf{Res}}_{ia} = 2\pi ie^{a \xi }
$$
Using \operatorname*{} rather than just \operatorname{} causes subscripts to appear directly under the symbol. But either \operatorname{} or \operatorname*{} results in context-dependent spacing, so that in expressions like$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$ $3\operatorname*{\textbf{Res}}_{ia} f$ or $3\operatorname*{\textbf{Res}}_{ia}(f)$ you see a small space after the $3,$ rather than just $3\textbf{Res}_{ia} f,$ and in the one without parentheses enclosing the $f$ you see some space before the $f. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy much better clarity this way.